# unix application benchmarking through time utility by running app in parallel

Tags: bash, unix, parallel-processing, cpu, benchmarking

i am trying to find the resources used by my application. i am using time utility advised here [stackoverflow.com/questions/560089/unix-command-for-benchmarking-code-running-k-times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560089/unix-command-for-benchmarking-code-running-k-times)

i used command as `time (for i in $(seq 100); do ./mycode; done)` as suggested by one of the answers.

problem: application run one by one but not n parallel. i need to run mycode 100/1000 times in parallel. any suggestion how to run application in parallel more than once. In other words how to run above command 100 times so 100X100 instances will be running at the same time.
I am also not able to place any format switch along with for loop. 
i tried  `time -v (for i in $(seq 100); do ./mycode; done)` for verbose output

note: I also tried /usr/bin/time and complete switch --verbose 
**EDIT:** I changed my code as per instructions from Cyrus reply. simultaneous ruuning of mycode is solved. but still I am looking for my second question how to get verbose output of time utility by using -v or --verbose.

Comment: Take a look at GNU parallel.

Comment: @Cyrus ---still unable to make command for my problem. plz help